# How do you create a semi-oval design CSS

Tags: css

I am not exactly sure how to describe it but I want to create this curved design with CSS:

[image]

The current bad solution is creating a semi-oval in white that cuts into the bottom color but creating a semi-oval is not very smooth. Here is what I have:

[image]

My code for the semi-oval:

```
<div style={{
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      height: '100px',
      width: '100%',
      borderRadius: '50%/100%',
      borderTopLeftRadius: '0',
      borderTopRightRadius: '0',
      position: 'absolute',
      left: '50%',
      transform: 'translate(-50%, 0%)'
    }}>

</div>
```

The top picture looks a lot smoother which is what I am trying to go for.

Comment: Why don't you just use an svg to do that? That sounds wayyy better than using css for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase it's `width` to have something more smooth

```css
div {
      background: red;
      height: 100px;
      width: 150%;
      border-radius: 100%;
      border-top-left-radius: 0;
      border-top-right-radius: 0;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0%;
      transform: translate(-20%, 0%)
      }
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use svg to do the job. The site on the top picture `https://www.circle.com/` actually used an svg to do that, [link to svg](https://www.circle.com/hubfs/up-gradient-tint.svg)

Comment: He didn't ask to use svg.